# How to treat as one all the instances in a csv file that have the same id with pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, pandas

I have two `.csv` as follows:

csv 1:

```
id,content,label
id_1,carga superior forma frontal programa majo eficiencia energético lavadora solo,5
id_2,modelo electrolux,4
```

csv 2:

```
id,content,label
id_1,carga superior forma frontal programa majo eficiencia energético lavadora solo,5
id_2,modelo electrolux,4
id_1,como te encuentras,5
id_2,hola como estas,4
```

In both `.csv` files the ids are the same  `id_1` and `id_2`. When I read with pandas with the `read_csv` function and compute the count of the data it says that I have 4 instances. How can I treat as one the instances that have the same `id` with pandas?. Any idea of how to aproach this?, thanks in advance guys.

When I say "treat as one", I mean something like this:

```
id,content,label
id_1,carga superior forma frontal programa majo eficiencia energético lavadora solo como te encuentras,5
id_2,modelo electrolux hola como estas,4
```

Comment: Do you want to combine csv1 and csv2 - or are you trying to just simplify/group the content column in csv2? Are the "labels" always the same (and if not, how do you want to treat their joining?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MarktheGraph. Yes I am trying to "combine" several .csv files that have the same `id` and different `content`. Yes the labels are always the same.

Comment: I would like to merge them in one file.

Comment: In your example CSV1 and the first two lines of CSV2 appear to be duplicates - do you want to eliminate duplicate rows?

Comment: No. The ids are the same, but the content is different. I would like to place the different content in the same id. For example something like this, this is the desired output: `id,content,label
id_1,carga superior forma frontal programa majo eficiencia energético lavadora solo como te encuentras,5
id_2,modelo electrolux hola como estas,4`

Comment: I would like to merge the diferent contents in one id. Thanks .......@MarktheGraph

Comment: the first line of CSV1 and CSV2 look the same to me?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is only small, this is a bit kludgy, but should work ...

I have not looked at merging, because I am not sure of the relationship between CSV1 and CSV2 in your example.

```
from StringIO import StringIO

csv2 = """
id,content,label
id_1,carga superior forma frontal programa majo eficiencia energético lavadora solo,5
id_2,modelo electrolux,4
id_1,como te encuentras,5
id_2,hola como estas,4"""
csv2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv2), header=0, index_col=None, skipinitialspace=True)

output = pd.DataFrame()
for u in csv2['id'].unique():
    rows = csv2[csv2['id']==u]
    text_rows = ' '.join(rows.content.tolist())
    label = int(rows['label'].iat[0])
    output = output.append(pd.DataFrame({'id':[u], 'content':[text_rows], 'label':[label]}))

output.index = range(len(output))
print (output)
```